# hidesBottomBarWhenPushed of UIViewController

Tags: iphone, ios

I need to clarification for hidesBottomBarWhenPushed method of UIViewController as apple documentation is not enough in this regard.

I have tabbar controller based application in which I have used separate navigation controller s for each tab. Navigation controller can have toolbar at the bottom. So my question is when I set "hidesBottomBarWhenPushed" to true for a new controller which I am going to push, should it hide both tabbar and toolbar or only tabbar? As per Apple documentation, this flag is applicable for toolbar also. CUrrently behavior is this flag is having effect on tabbar only.
I know that we should have one bar at any time, but I am just wondering how this api is working in behind.

Thanking you in advance for your support.

Answer (score 0):

It should hide any bar that is visible at the bottom. That is why the name is generic- 'bottom bar'.

Comment: But this is not happening. I checked this with one sample: while pushing one new controller on navigation controller in one of tabs of sample, I have set this flag to TRUE. This hides tabbar correctly. Then I have made toolbar visible on current navigation controller. Then while pushing again a new controller, i have use this function. So now this toolbar should be hidden as it is at bottom now. But this is not happening.

Comment: Where are you setting hidesBottomBarWhenPushed to YES?

Comment: Note this issue is still present in iOS 15, so it may be a deliberate issue. You can see it when you set hidesBottomBarWhenPushed to true on the navigationController prior to your pushViewController call.